# jQuery: How to add and handle the beforeChange event to input element?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have read all the official documentation of jQuery 1.7.2, but I cannot find any detail about the 'beforechange' event (or something like that) which help me control some rules before allowing the element to change its value. Is there any plugins provide this handler?
Thank you so much!

Comment: What is your aim? As you know, js has no such event, so it has to be simulated.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery api doesnot provide the 'beforechange' event but instead provide great flexibility to write our own custom events. We can define our own custom events and can be triggered when the events is fired. 
For example for input elements we can have onkeydown or onkeypress events and when fired we can trigger our custom events to control some rules.

The following link provides information for creating custom events. Its very simple and flexible.

http://scriptble.com/2009/05/custom-events-with-jquery